# How do I share data between custom Ant tasks?

Tags: java, ant, static, task

I wrote two different custom Ant tasks.  They are trying to share data through a static member in a base class.  This is not working for me.

I assume I am using static members correctly within Java.  I think this is a dynamic loading issue with the Java VM.  However, I am a relative newbie with Java.

Since Ant custom tasks are mapped at runtime using the `taskdef` task, the Ant build engine must dynamically load this code via java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance().

Is there a trick to make this work?

Note: This works fine in "regular" Java code... it is the dynamic loading of Ant that is the issue.

Example classes:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;

public class AntCustomTaskShared extends Task {
    private static Integer _static_bigdata = null;
    public Integer get_bigdata() {
        if (_static_bigdata == null) {
            log("alloc");  // from ant Task class
            _static_bigdata = new Integer(0);
        }
        return _static_bigdata;
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;

public class AntCustomTask1 extends AntCustomTaskShared {
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        Integer big_data = get_bigdata();  // "alloc" is printed
        // do stuff with big_data
        log("I'm doing big stuff");
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;

public class AntCustomTask2 extends AntCustomTaskShared {
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        Integer big_data = get_bigdata();  // "alloc" is printed (again)
        // do stuff with big_data
        log("I'm doing big stuff again");
    }
}
```

Example Ant build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyTask" basedir="." default="init">
   <target name="init"
           description="test the custom task"
   >
      <taskdef name="CustomTask1"
               classname="AntCustomTask1"
               classpath="C:\my_custom_ant_task_class_files"
      />
      <taskdef name="CustomTask2"
               classname="AntCustomTask2"
               classpath="C:\my_custom_ant_task_class_files"
      />
      <CustomTask1/>
      <CustomTask2/>
   </target>
</project>
```

Do all of the above and you will see "alloc" logged twice.  I cannot get these two custom tasks to share the "big data".

I am running ant 1.8.1 on Windows with these two env vars:

- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
- CLASSPATH=(empty)

Hint: If you want to step into this custom task from an Ant (1.8) process, set your breakpoints here:

- `org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main()`
- `org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute()`

Comment: could you post a simple build that illustrates this?  I've tried this locally and it appears to work for me - no second alloc is printed.

Comment: Using your sample build I don't get two calls to the BigData constructor.  Do see two allocs now though: one from println, and one from logger.  I've got all the classes in one directory fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, but poorly (or not?) documented on the Ant website.  (I will commit a patch to the Ant docs to correct this situation!)

I needed to use the attribute `loaderref` on `taskdef` nodes.  The token is used to reference the ClassLoader (and share it).  After, static members are shared between custom tasks correctly.

Corrected Ant build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyTask" basedir="." default="init">
   <target name="init"
           description="test the custom task"
   >
      <taskdef name="CustomTask1"
               classname="AntCustomTask1"
               classpath="C:\my_custom_ant_task_class_files"
               loaderref="my_shared_class_loader"
      />
      <taskdef name="CustomTask2"
               classname="AntCustomTask2"
               classpath="C:\my_custom_ant_task_class_files"
               loaderref="my_shared_class_loader"
      />
      <CustomTask1/>
      <CustomTask2/>
   </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I still don't see the description of this use in the documentation for Ant. Did you submit a patch in the end?

Answer (score 0):

This is less elegant, but you could try sharing the information via the `System.setProperty` and `System.getProperty` calls.  The ANT class loading is definitely different then a normal Java application.